# array bidimensional javascript

Tags: javascript, array

Tengo que conseguir esta estructura en `Javascript`:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En ella guardare en la primera columna objetos y en la segunda una cantidad que sera un numero entero. Lo tengo que crear con array bidimensional. He intentando mil forma, pero algo se me escapa. Lo mas cerca que estoy es esto:

```
arrayCompras[0]=new Array();

arrayCompras[0][0]=objetoProducto;
arrayCompras[0][1]=1;
```

Pero no se si voy. ¿Aparte si quiero introducir mas datos en el `array` como lo hago?
Si intento esto.

```
arrayCompras[1][0]=objetoProducto2;
arrayCompras[1][1]=2;
```

Me salta un error.

> Cannot set property '0' of undefined.

Soluciones?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Cannot set property '0' of undefined.` es porque no definiste el `array` antes de acceder al indice , como solución puedes definir un `array` `[]`, y añadir los elementos directamente como tipo `array` con `push`

```js
let producto = { 'nombre': 'Milk' , 'Edad' : 20};
let producto1 = { 'nombre': 'Stack' , 'Edad' : 53};

var array = [];

//añadimos dos elementos de tipo array 
array.push( [producto,  1]);
array.push( [producto1 ,  71]);


//Impresión del array antes
console.log(array[1]);
console.log("Cantidad " + array[1][1]);

//Impresión del array modificado la cantidad del segundo
// elemento , posición 1 en el array
array[1][1]=66;

// Cambios reflejados
console.log(array[1]);

console.log("Cantidad " + array[1][1]);
```

Answer (score 5):

Falta la inicializacion de cada array
con el siguiente for puedes inicializarlo:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  arrayBidimensional[i] = new Array(2);
}
```

y ahora resolviendo tu duda:

```js
var arrayBidimensional= new Array(4);
for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  arrayBidimensional[i] = new Array(2);
}

arrayBidimensional[0][0]="1";
arrayBidimensional[0][1]="2 ";
arrayBidimensional[1][0]="3";
arrayBidimensional[1][1]="4";

console.log("arrayBidimensional[0][0]",arrayBidimensional[0][0]);
console.log("arrayBidimensional[0][1]",arrayBidimensional[0][1]);
console.log("arrayBidimensional[1][0]",arrayBidimensional[1][0]);
console.log("arrayBidimensional[1][1]",arrayBidimensional[1][1]);
```

Answer (score 3):

- Respecto al error: *Cannot set property '0' of undefined.*

  El error lo recibes porque al hacer `arrayCompras[1][0]=objetoProducto2;` te has olvidad de inicializar el arreglo en la posición `arrayCompras[1]`, es decir, usando tu código seria `arrayCompras[1] = new Array()`.
- Respecto a: *¿Aparte si quiero introducir mas datos en el `array` como lo hago?*

  Puedes usar [`array.push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/push)

  > El método `push()` agrega uno o más elementos al final de un array y devuelve la nueva longitud del array.

#### Ejemplo:

```js
var arrayCompras = [], // es equivalente a hacer new Array()
  objetoProducto = {'uno': 1},
  objetoProducto2 = {'dos': 2};

// ¿Como agregar elementos al arreglo?
arrayCompras.push([objetoProducto, 1]);
// es equivalente a:
//   arrayCompras[0][0] = objetoProducto
//   arrayCompras[0][1] = 1

arrayCompras.push([objetoProducto2, 2]);
// es equivalente a:
//   arrayCompras[1][0] = objetoProducto2
//   arrayCompras[1][1] = 2

//
console.log(arrayCompras[0][0]);
console.log(arrayCompras[0][1]);
console.log(arrayCompras[1][0]);
console.log(arrayCompras[1][1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Gracias por las respuestas, todas muy correctas.
El tema del problema es que de inicio yo no se las posiciones que tendrá el array compras,el programa se basa en carrito de la compra que añado productos y su stock. Si el producto ya existe, comprobado por id, sumo uno a la posición de la cantidad, si no existe pues le creo. Al final he resuelto el problema de la siguiente manera:

```js
Carrito.prototype.insertarProducto = function (p)
{
    if (this._compras.length == 0) //Si la lista compras esta vacia la inicio con el primer producto     
    {
        this._compras = new Array();
        this._compras[0] = new Array();
        this._compras[0][0] = p;
        this._compras[0][1] = 1;
        return true;
    }

    if (this._compras.length > 0)
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < this._compras.length; i++) {
          
            if (this._compras[i][0].getId() === p.getId())//Con un for y un if compruebo si ya exite el id
            {
                this._compras[i][1] += 1;   //Si ya existe le aumento la cantidad   
                return false;
            }

        }
        
        //Si no hay id significa que no existe
        var tamaño = this._compras.length;
        this._compras[tamaño] = new Array();
        this._compras[tamaño][0] = p;
        this._compras[tamaño][1] = 1;
        return true;
    }
};
```

Quizás no sea la mas optima pero funciona correctamente.
Un saludo y gracias por todas las respuestas.